# How to create a tar of directory structure

Tags: tar

I want to copy the directories into another server; however don't need to copy the files of the directories. So a tar of empty directories is the one that I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `cpio`, not `tar` for this. First, cd to the top level directory you want to copy.

```
find . -type d -print0 | cpio -o -0 >/tmp/archive.cpio
```

Then copy /tmp/archive.cpio to your remote host. You can do it in one step:

```
find . -type d -print0 | cpio -o -0 | ssh user@remotehost "cd targetdir; cpio -i"
```

By the way, the `-print0` and `-0` options are useful/needed when filenames contain non-printable characters, ie, newlines.

Comment: Hi Otheus. I entered the command you gave.. However; it came up as cpio: illegal option -- 0. By the way i am using HPUX and the structure needs copying back to Linux. Thats the tricky bit here.

Comment: Then omit `-0` and replace `-print0` with `-print`. This is almost never a problem.

Comment: It works  like a charm.. Thank you so much.. You cant imagine how much time you saved.. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 4):

This the command you will need:

```
find . -type d -print0 | tar cf folderstructure.tar --null --files-from - --no-recursion
```

it generates the file `folderstructure.tar` with the folder structure without the files.

Comment: Hi jcbermu.. I am using HPUX that needs migration to Linux. Can you advise on what to do here please.

Comment: @DineshNidamanuru Sorry , the command is for linux (bash) and on HPUX there could be little differerences in syntax. i don't know about them